# Impossible to login through ssh (keeps waiting after password), workaround?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, recovery-mode

I recently installed an Ubuntu 17.10 Server, with not too much fancy software or customizations.

When I ssh to my machine, it asks for my password. The password prompt has my correct username. **When I enter the password, it just keeps waiting forever.**

Note that when I deliberately enter a *wrong* password, it says "Permission denied, please try again" so the checking mechanism is actually working. But upon entering the right password, nothing seems to happen (waits indefinitely, I have to terminate my SSH client).

This has worked fine before, I actually logged in earlier today without problems. I certainly didn't change anything in my configuration, or add any login or startup scripts or anything.

This machine is on a remote physical location, so it would really suck if I have to go there and physically access or reset the machine. Is there any other way to access it?

For example is there a 'recovery login mode' with SSH or something? Or is there a way to make ssh say what it's waiting for (and optionally skip that) after I entered my password?

Comment: Can you access the machine at all through SSH or via a TTY session?

Comment: What do you mean? When I try to access through SSH, the above happens. I'm not sure what TTY is, how do I use that?

Comment: It's possible that your login has successfully authenticated, but for some reason the remote shell is failing to initialize properly - have you tried typing a simple command such as `ls` after it gets "stuck"? or starting SSH with an explicit shell command e.g. `ssh -t username@server '/bin/dash -i'`

Comment: How exactly do `ssh to the machine`?

Comment: @derHugo I just enter `ssh username@ipaddress` on my own PC (macOs) with the appropriate username and ipaddress for the remove machine

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the suggestion, I happened to be on the PC's location today so I just rebooted it manually. If it happens again I'll try that!

Comment: Also running ` ssh` with verbose option (`-v`, `-vv` or `-vvv`) might eventually give use more insight